# Calculating sales for a particular weekday in a given period in teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I have  a table with transaction, date and their respective sales value. I need to calculate  sum of Sales of all the distinct transactions on all Saturdays between date x and y. Teradata doesn't have a datename, datepart function. How can I do this?

Comment: give your table name and fields.It'll be easier to solve

Answer (score 2):

I'm not Teradata expert, I don't even know it but I've found something. It's not a solution it's only suggestion of course, because you tell nothing about your db schema.

Source [Dates and Times in Teradata (thru V2R4.1)](http://www.teradataforum.com/l030515a.htm):

> Computing the day of the week for a given date is not easy in SQL. If you need a weekday, I recommend that you look it up in the view sys_calendar.calendar (or join to it), thus:

```
select day_of_week
   from sys_calendar.calendar
   where calendar_date = date '2003-05-01';


day_of_week
-----------
          5  [i.e. Thursday]
```

Comment: My DB schema is fairly complex. After using a couple of joins, I get a schema of Date, Sales, Transaction_Id.  BTW, if I have a date range on which I need to find for all the Saturdays, how will one go about it?

Comment: Never mind. Got it. Did an as inner join sys_calendar.calendar as cal on cal.calendar_date=my_table.date where cal.day_of_week=7. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Did an inner join as
`inner join sys_calendar.calendar as cal on cal.calendar_date=my_table.date where cal.day_of_week=7`